# Separate cell content after "-" for multiple columns at once

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

```
 -------------------------------------------- 
|  Visible |   Actual formula   |  I need    |
 --------------------------------------------
|    0     |   =500-500         |  500       |
|    0     |   =10000-10000     |  10000     |
|    0     |   =1500-1500       |  1500      |
|    0     |   =750-750         |  750       |
|          |                    |            |
 --------------------------------------------
```

I can do above separation by using Text To Column from Data tab in MS Office Excel 2007.
But I have many columns which couldn't select and apply Text to column at once. Is it possible with any other easy way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to apply this method to multiple columns at once, right?
I don't see how this could be done without VBA, so here is my solution:

```
Sub text2columns()

separator = "-"
FirstCol = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByColumns, xlNext).Column
LastCol = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column

For i = LastCol To FirstCol Step -1

    Set test = ActiveSheet.Columns(i).Find(separator, , xlFormulas, xlPart)

    If Not test Is Nothing Then
        Set FirstCell = ActiveSheet.Columns(i).Find("*", , , , , xlNext)
        Set LastCell = ActiveSheet.Columns(i).Find("*", , , , , xlPrevious)

        Columns(i + 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Range(FirstCell, LastCell).TextToColumns Destination:=FirstCell, _
            DataType:=xlDelimited, Other:=True, OtherChar:=separator
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If

Next
End Sub
```

#### Quick overview

1. Iterate backwards through each column
2. Test if seperator string `-` is present in current column
3. If yes, insert an new column right next of it
4. And apply text-to-column method to current column

<sup>This macro will fail if you have more than one separator in any cell</sup>

#### Before

[image]

#### After

[image]

#### [Sample worksheet](http://ge.tt/3ASJDkK1/v/0)

Comment: Sorry dude, I didn't chk your answer for a long period.